# Why value assigned using Javascript to Primefaces inputText widget is not sent to server when readonly=true?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, readonly

I have created specific code that allow a user to load a dialog to specify some search criterias.

The code that call the dialog is

```
<i   class="fa fa-fw fa-dot-circle-o"
     onclick="PF('LoadLabelHomoVectoDialog').show();"
     />
<p:inputText
     id="CertificationCodeId"
     value="#{vC.postLabellingSearchCriteria.certificationCode}"
     readonly="true"
     />
```

The user click on icon and dialogbox is displayed.
The user make some action in dialog, click on OK button and `CertificationCodeId` inputText widget is filled directly using Javascript. I can see specific value in it.

Then on main page (not more in dialog), I click on SEARCH button to start a new search using criteria value found in `CertificationCodeId` inputText widget.

If `readonly` attribute equal "false", the widget value is correctly transmitted to ViewController on server.

If `readonly` attribute equal "true", the widget value is **NOT transmitted** to ViewController on server.

I thought that `readonly` attribute is only to prohibit user input, but not to prohibit value to be transmitted to server.

What do I wrong ?

Is that a Primefaces issue ?

There exists a answer to my problem to [Validate readonly components anyway on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088759/validate-readonly-components-anyway-on-form-submit/24089336#24089336) that is disctinct from what is proposed !!! What is proposed is a duplicate of the link I propose :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force JSF to process, validate and update readonly/disabled input components anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390081/force-jsf-to-process-validate-and-update-readonly-disabled-input-components-any)

Comment: Transmited or processed? Major difference. It is transmitted, just not processed

Answer (score 2):

JSF and PrimeFaces do not process values when inputs are disabled or readOnly for security purposes. So even a hacker enables the input and submits the form, JSF-PrimeFaces checks the component. So it is standard behavior. You need to enable it on server side.

Found here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=15632

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390081/force-jsf-to-process-validate-and-update-readonly-disabled-input-components-any

Comment: the following link give better explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088759/validate-readonly-components-anyway-on-form-submit/24089336#24089336

Answer (score 0):

Because I will that visible `inputText` is READ-ONLY, the only solution is to duplicate READ-ONLY `inputText` like this ...

```
<i   class="fa fa-fw fa-dot-circle-o"
     onclick="PF('LoadLabelHomoVectoDialog').show();"
     />
<p:inputText
     id="CertificationCodeId"
     value="#{vC.postLabellingSearchCriteria.certificationCode}"
     readonly="true"
     />
<p:inputText
     id="CertificationCodeIdBecauseJSFdontSentReadOnlyWidgetValueToServer"
     value="#{vC.postLabellingSearchCriteria.certificationCode}"
     style="display:none"
     />
```

The value of second widget is sent to server because it is not disabled or read-only.

In Javascript code, I must assign the two widget.

> JSF and PrimeFaces do not process values when inputs are disabled or
>   readOnly for security purposes. So even a hacker enables the input and
>   submits the form, JSF-PrimeFaces checks the component.

I think now, that issue that JSF/Primefaces want to avoid, is always there because an hacker can change content of the hidden widget.

The only thing I see is that the code is more complex and less readable :-)

Why to do simple when it is possible to do complex ?

Comment: @kukeltje - I have read the communicated duplicate link. But have you read the duplicate link that I have communicated ? Your duplicate link if from 2015 and my duplicate link is from 2014 ! In fact your duplicate link is a duplicate of question posted in 2014 ! But perhaps I misunderstand what you will say with 'No' ! But in all case, the answer to my question found is correct in 2014 and 2015 posts. Personally, I find that BalsuC answer in 2014 post is more documented.